# Are VoIP questions off topic?

Tags: discussion

Are VoIP questions off-topic?

Obviously [voice over IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) (VoIP) uses a computer. VoIP uses the Internet to operate, so I would think VoIP questions fall into the category of "computer hardware/software". Nevertheless, I see that a lot of the VoIP questions have been closed, but some are open. What are the on-topic boundaries here, if any?

Answer (score 12):

From the [voip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/voip) tag:

> VoIP questions should cover configuration of softphones, voice software (such as Asterisk) that runs on computers (no hardphones or PBXs) or troubleshooting VoIP quality and connectivity issues by means of computer hardware or software (tcpdump, wireshark).

So presumably questions that cover these topics are considered on-topic.

Comment: If they're on-topic, why did those questions get closed, you think? :/

Comment: @SarahofGaia 32 from 647 are closed. Some of those are duplicates. A lot of the remaining closed questions are either "shopping" or "product, service, or learning material recommendations" and would be off-topic even if they weren't specifically VoIP questions. Just because something has a particular tag doesn't magically make it on-topic.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. I wasn't trying to be rude or snarky or anything; please don't be annoyed... °́ ◜ °̀

Comment: @SarahofGaia What makes you think I'm annoyed? ;)